# Draw directional arrows on a given line.

Tags: geometry

Consider the lines in the image below:

[image]

Given a set of arbitrary points $p1$ and $p2$ where the direction of travel is from the former to the latter, I want to be able to directional arrow marks as in the image above.

I got as far as calculating the mid-points of the lines but could not figure out how to cater to various combinations of $x1<x2$, $x1>x2$, etc. Is there a direct way to calculate these points? **EDIT**: By direct, I mean in one step without conditioning of where the points lie with respect to each other.

$f1(p1, p2) = $ get the line coordinates of the left directional marker.
$f2(p1, p2) = $ get the line coordinates of the right directional marker.

Answer (score 0):

vector, perpendicular to $(x, y)$ is $(y, -x)$, so if you add that to your midpoint (normalized appropriately) and subtract a fraction of the vector you already have you'll get one of your arrow lines end.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ be the length of the line. Then the points on the arrow can all be obtained by expressions of the form $$(x_m+ a\cdot \frac{x_2-x_1}{l}+b\cdot \frac{y_2-y_1}l, y_m+c\cdot \frac{x_2-x_1}{l}+d\cdot \frac{y_2-y_1}l)$$
where $(x_m,y_m)$ is the midpoint and you can select the the constants $a,b,c,d$ according to your taste.

Comment: Thank you. I am assuming that by $x2-x1$, you are always referring to the absolute values. Or does that not matter?